# read data come from firebase using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read data from firebase in python. and i want to read it using pandas.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import firebase_admin


# get list data
cred = "card.json"

login = credentials.Certificate(cred)

#initialize firebase 
# firebase_admin.initialize_app(login)

#reading from the database
db = firestore.client()

lists = db.collection("Lists").stream()
```

It work just fine. but when I try to use pandas. I'm not sure how to do it. I tried this.

```
listing = pd.DataFrame(lists)
print(listing)
```

it printed this:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

am I missing something? am I doing something wrong? please help.

Comment: Try looking at [Firestore to Pandas Dataframe](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/pandas/firestore-to-pandas-dataframe/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created empty data frame. just added the column name.
then go through the data coming from firebase then add it to the data frame that I created.
like this:

```
data = {'ListID': [], 'Title': [], 'Description': [], 'Cover': [], 'Access': [], 'uid': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for list in lists:
    l = list.to_dict()
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ListID': [l.get("ListID")],
                'Title': [l.get("Title")],
                'Description': [l.get("Description")],
                'Cover': [l.get("Cover")],
                'Access': [l.get("Access")],
                'uid': [l.get("uid")]})
    
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index = True, axis = 0)
```